# How do I select version when building angleproject on MacOS ( latest M2 machine)

Tags: c++, google-angle

starting on this and following the instructions here:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/+/main/doc/DevSetup.md

I got the "depot_tools"  and do what they said to fetch the source from git.

```
mkdir angle
cd angle
fetch angle
```

This succeeds.
So I want to select a branch or tag I assume before the following build steps to basically check out the "latest stable" version which looks like it is:

"origin/chromium/5454"

Then build it, and try it in a test application.
There is no hint on how to do this properly in the DevSetup.md.   The depot_tools "fetch" leaves it at the "main" branch.  Fetch has has a step where it does "synching projects"

Is it appropriate to just after the depot_tools/fetch is complete to just do a "git checkout origin/chromium/5454" ?

No hints in the setup doc how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Well though it is not actually said this is proper in the docs,  I did in the root directory of the source do a git checkout.  It appears after the "project synchronization" step in the "fetch" there are only two ".git" roots.  One "./build" only has a master branch.

The root of the whole "angle" folder seems to be the one that is versioned, and it all built ( takes 20 minutes !! ) without error after checking out a specific version.

Though whenever there is more than one repository in a tree I am nervous that it might not be in sync unless given and explicit procedure for making sure it is.